# Is it possible that Drag and Drop events in WPF are not firing reliable?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I wonder if D&D events not always firing (DragLeave/DragEnter).

I implemented a D&D feature in my WPF GUI. While dragging some element around I 'dragleave' a GUI element. Normally it fires an appropriate 'DragLeave' event, but not always. I fear, that for some speed reasons sometimes these events get not fired reliable. If that's the case, how can I overcome these issue?

Comment: https://www.success.com/19-quotes-about-facing-your-fears/

Comment: Per the MSN’s article: [This event is not raised if the element's AllowDrop property is false.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dragdrop.dragleave?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) I’d first check if AllowDrop is set to True on the element in question.

Comment: @KeithStein: thank you for your comment - yes the AllowDrop was set

Answer (score 0):

**Short Version:**
I wrote some sample app to check it myself - and yes - the DragLeave event is not fired reliable.

**Long Version:**

*What I did:*

I placed a `Label` as a draggable object inside a `StackPanel`. Then I implemented the code for the `MouseMove` and  `DragLeave` events. An additional `TextBlock` - added to the `StackPanel` as well - served as event output. If the `DragLeave` handler gets called, I changed the `Text` `Property` of the `TextBlock` to '*DragLeave occured*'. Afterwards I tested it dragging the `Label` towards the `StackPanel`.

*What I recognized:*

If I was **fast** enough or pressed the mouse button **close to** the border of the `Label`, the `DragLeave` event was **not** fired. If I did it **slow**, everything worked **fine** as expected.

*What I conclude:*

I guess, if the mouse leaves the `Label` before the '`DoDragDrop`' thread is initiated, the event is not fired, since the mouse is already outside the `Label`. So there is a small glitch between starting the D&D and the firing of the first event.

One can see the same behavior in the `DragOver/MouseMove` handler. The faster you move the mouse, the fewer points (e.GetPosition(...)) you can capture in the event handler.

Problem is, that for the `DragLeave` that missing event can be critical, since it is only fired once. However, the `DragOver` event is fired very often during a dragging and a missing event can be balanced by the next `DragOver` event directly afterwards.